# JQuery to remove class from sibling's elements

Tags: jquery

Each row has 3 images but one of those 3 images have a class active.

```
.active{border: 1px solid red;}
```

Active image has border around it (by class active). Two images have np border (class empty)

All I want, onclick remove the border from currently active image and add to the one that is clicked.

I tried  all of these none worked:

```
$('#' + clkdImgId + ' img').parent().children('.active').removeClass('active'); // fails;
$('#' + clkdImgId + ' img').siblings().find("img.active").hide(); //fails
$('#' + clkdImgId + ' img').closest('.active').removeClass('active');//fails
$('#' + clkdImgId + ' img').closest('.image').children('.active').hide();//fails
$('#' + clkdImgId + ' img').closest('img.active').removeClass('active');//fails
$('#' + clkdImgId + ' img').closest('.active').hide();//fails


function setBrder(rowId, imgId)
{
  var clkdImgId = 'img' + rowId + imgId;//this gives me img12, img13 etc correctly

  //set class on the clicked 
  $('#' + clkdImgId + ' img').addClass('active');// this works

$('#' + clkdImgId + ' img').parent().children('.active').removeClass('active'); // fails;
    $('#' + clkdImgId + ' img').siblings().find("img.active").hide(); //fails
    $('#' + clkdImgId + ' img').closest('.active').removeClass('active');//fails
    $('#' + clkdImgId + ' img').closest('.image').children('.active').hide();//fails
    $('#' + clkdImgId + ' img').closest('img.active').removeClass('active');//fails
    $('#' + clkdImgId + ' img').closest('.active').hide();//fails

}


HTMLs:

<table><tr><td>
                        <div id="img11" class="image">
                            <img class="active" src=".."> <- REMOVE this .active
                        </div>
                        <div id="img12" class="image">
                            <img class="" src="..">       <- ADD HERE IF THIS CLICKED
                            <div onclick="setBrder('1', 2);" class="overlay">Set</div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="img13" class="image">
                            <img class="" src="..">
                                <div onclick="setBrder('1', 3);" class="overlay">Set</div>
                        </div>
                    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
                        <div id="img11" class="image">
                            <img class="" src="..">
                            <div onclick="setBrder('2', 1);" class="overlay">Set</div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="img12" class="image">
                            <img class="active" src="..">                        
                        </div>
                        <div id="img13" class="image">
                            <img class="" src="..">
                                <div onclick="setBrder('2', 3);" class="overlay">Set</div>
                        </div>
                    </td></tr>
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass all those number arguments to `setBrder`? Why not just pass `this` and use `.parent()` to go up to the `DIV`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `clkdImgId` is the id of the `div` element, so you need to find the `img` elements inside the sibling elements of `clkdImgId` element

```
$('#' + clkdImgId).siblings().find('img').removeClass('active');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vdqW8/)

Comment: Yours work but mine didn't only because I added find('img.active') instead of 'img': $('#' + clkdImgId + ' img').siblings().find("img.active").hide();

Comment: @kheya why are you hiding the elements

Answer (score 1):

Clear all active class then add it to the one you clicked:

```
 $('.overlay').on('click', function() {
       $('img').removeClass( "active" );
       $(this).parent().find('img').addClass("active");
 });
```

Comment: I don't click the image, but the overlay

Comment: updated:: when overlay is clicked we remove all active class then find the image that is within the parent element for the overlay that was clicked and add the active class :: that was a mouthful

Answer (score 1):

try this, you can remove all active classes and then add class to current clicked element

```
$(document).on('click','.image',function(){
     $(this).parent().find('img').removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have that complicated structure and redundant code like that, just do like this:

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="img11" class="image">
            <img class="active" src=".."/>
        </div>
        <div id="img12" class="image">
            <img class="" src=".."/>
            <div class="overlay">
                Set
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="img13" class="image">
            <img class="" src=".."/>
            <div class="overlay">
                Set
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="img11" class="image">
            <img class="" src=".."/>
            <div class="overlay">
                Set
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="img12" class="image">
            <img class="active" src=".."/>
        </div>
        <div id="img13" class="image /">
            <img class="" src=".."/>
            <div class="overlay">
                Set
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.overlay').click(function() {
    $('.image img').removeClass('active');
    $(this).prev().addClass('active');
})
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62AL7/2/)**

Comment: your demo is broken. I don;t click the image, I click the overlay.